TeXbook - Chapter 12: Glue - Exercise 12.8/12.11/12.12
I have learnt the link of 12.8 and the link of 12.13 as my understanding, the answer illustrate of the 12.8 is as below(but not elegantly):

[Qusetion of 12.8] Assume that \box1 is 1pt high, 1pt deep, and 1pt wide; \box2 is 2pt high, 2pt deep, and 2pt wide. A third box is formed by saying:\setbox3=\hbox to3pt{\hfil\lower3pt\box1\hskip-3pt plus3fil\box2}.
What are the height, depth, and width of \box3? Describe the position of the reference
points of boxes 1 and 2 with respect to the reference point of box 3.


[Answer of 12.8] \box3 is 2pt high, 4pt deep, 3pt wide. Starting at the reference point of \box3, go right .75pt and down 3pt to reach the reference point of \box1; or go right 1pt to reach the reference point of \box2.

I am not sure that the following figure is RIGHT, especially for the shift of the baseline and the reference point.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\section{Horizontal Box Glue(12.8)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A, 2/0/B, 3/0/C, 6/0/D, 8/0/E}
    \draw (2,1) rectangle (3,-1) (6,2) rectangle (8,-2);
    \draw[dashed] (B)--(C) (D)--(E);
    \tkzDrawSegment[dim={glue1,0pt,}](A,B)
    \tkzDrawSegment[dim={glue2,0pt,}](C,D)
    \fill[cyan] (B) circle (1pt) (D) circle (1pt);
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-6cm]
        \draw[dashed] (0,1) rectangle (1,-1);
        \draw (1,2) rectangle (3,-2) (0,-2) rectangle (1,-4);
        \draw[orange,thick] (-.1,-4.1) rectangle (3.1,2.1);
        \node at (.5,-2.5) {$\rm box1$};
        \node at (2,1) {$\rm box2$};
        \tkzDefPoints{0/-3/A, 1/-3/B, 1/0/C, 3/0/D}
        \draw[dashed] (A)--(B) (C)--(D);
        \fill[cyan] (.75,-3) circle (1pt) (1,0) circle (1pt) (0,0) circle (1pt);
        \tkzDefPoints{.5/1/X, .5/-2/Y}
        \tkzDrawSegment[dim={$3pt$,0pt,}](X,Y)
        \draw[cyan] (1.8,-3.5) node[below] {$\scriptstyle \rm RP~of~Box3$} -- (.75,-3) (-1,-.5) node[below] {$\scriptstyle \rm RP~of~Box1$} -- (0,0) (1.8,-.5) node[below] {$\scriptstyle \rm RP~of~Box2$} -- (1,0);
        \tkzDefPoints{0/2.5/AA, .75/2.5/BB, 1.75/2.5/CC, 1.75/2.8/DD, 1/2.8/EE, 1/3.2/FF, 3/3.2/GG}
        \tkzDrawSegment[dim={$\scriptstyle .75$,0pt,}](AA,BB)
        \tkzDrawSegment[dim={$\scriptstyle 1$,0pt,}](BB,CC)
        \tkzDrawSegment[dim={$\scriptstyle -.75$,0pt,}](DD,EE)
        \tkzDrawSegment[dim={$\scriptstyle 2$,0pt,}](FF,GG)
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

And for the further problem in 12.11 & 12.12:

[Question of 11.11 & 12.12]

12.11 \box1 is 1 pt high, 1 pt deep, and 1 pt wide; \box2 is 2 pt high,2 pt deep, and 2 pt wide; the baselineskip, lineskip, and lineskiplimit are all zero; and the \boxmaxdepth is very large. A third box is formed by saying \setbox3=\vbox to3pt{\moveright3pt\box1\vskip-3pt plus3fil\box2}. What are the height, depth, and width of \box3? Describe the position of the reference points of boxes 1 and 2 with respect to the reference point of box 3.


12.12 Under the assumptions of the previous exercise, but with 12.12 \baselineskip=9pt minus3fil, describe \box4 after \setbox4=\vbox to4pt{\vss\box1\moveleft4pt\box2\vss}.




[Answer of 12.11] The interline glue will be zero, and the natural height is 1 + 1 - 3 + 2 = 1 pt (because the depth of \box2 isn’t included in the natural height); so the glue will ultimately become \vskip-1pt when it’s set. Thus, \box3 is 3 pt high, 2 pt deep, 4 pt wide. Its reference point coincides with that of \box2; to get to the reference point of \box1 you go up 2 ptand right 3 pt.




[Answer of 12.12] The interline glue will be 6 pt minus 3 fil; the final depth will be zero, since \box2 is followed by glue; the natural height is 12 pt; and the shrinkability is 5 fil. So \box4 will be 4 pt high, 0 pt deep, 1 pt wide, and it will contain five items: \vskip-1.6pt, \box1, \vskip1.2pt, \moveleft4pt\box2, \vskip-1.6pt. Starting at the reference point of \box4, you get to the reference point of \box1 by going up 4.6 pt, or to the reference point of \box2 by going up .4 pt and left 4 pt. (For example, you go up 4 pt to get to the upper left corner of \box4; then down -1.6 pt, i.e., up 1.6 pt, to get to the upper left corner of \box1; then down 1 pt to reach its reference point. This problem is clearly academic, since it’s rather ridiculous to include infinite shrinkability in the baselineskip.)


I get extremely dizzy in (1)calculate the natural hegiht/width distance(especially the case with glue appended to the last box??) and (2)the location of baseline of each \box and (3)the so-call Reference Point when two boxes are attached or some of them shifted? And in 12.12, I also very confused about that why the width of \box4 is only 1pt?
I have tried my best to make it foucus on the but its coverage turn out to be a little wide.I will go over the dangerous bend in th book, but I think I actually need the diagram illstration to better understanding the conception of glue of the \box. BTW, is there better method the show the figure more easier and clearly. It takes me a lot of time to get the un-elegant figure(T_T)
If the content of my question is not proper, I will supplement it. Best Regards.

in the 12.8 case the boxes overlap, as showed by your arrows with lengths, but your diagram makes them look adjacent without overlapping. you need .7pt space then box 1 which is 1pt wide then -.75pt space then box 2 which is 2pt wide, so a total width of 3pt with the boxes overlaping by .7tpt

I'm not sure you need pictures.
Exercise 12.8
Let's compute the natural width of \box3: there is glue in the amounts of

0pt plus 1fil (from \hfil
-3pt plus 3fil

Then there are two boxes, 1pt and 2pt wide respectively. Therefore the natural width is 0pt. There is first-order infinite glue which will be used for reaching the 3pt target. In total four units of stretchable glue, in the ratio 1:3, so we get

glue of 0.75pt
\box1 (lowered)
glue of -0.75pt
\box2

The second glob of glue will be -0.75pt: -3pt from the natural width and 2.25pt from the stretch component.
What about the reference points? It depends on what you consider. The original reference point of \box1 will sit 0.75pt from the left edge an 3pt below the baseline; the reference point used for typesetting will obviously be at the enclosing box baseline, hence 3pt higher than the original one. The reference point of \box2 will be 2pt from the right edge, hence 1pt from the left edge.
The width of the final box is 3pt, the height 2pt and the depth 4pt.
In the picture below, the black frame around the enclosing box (\box3) is drawn outside the box; the red frames around \box1 (lowered) and \box2 are drawn inside the box. The blue line represents the baseline of \box3 (the same as the outer horizontal box being built).

Exercise 12.11
Here we need to remember that when a \vbox is typeset, the reference point of the last box therein will be at the baseline of the outer level, unless \boxmaxdepth is small, which is not the case here.
Since no paragraph is started in \box3, the resulting width will be determined by the widest item in the vertical list, taking \moveright shifting into account.
Saying \vbox to 3pt means that the height of the built box will be 3pt and the depth will be the one of the last item, in this case 2pt.
The two boxes are stacked. Now we need to understand the vertical space. Since depth of the top box plus height of the bottom box minus \baselineskip exceeds \lineskiplimit, instead of (adapted) \baselineskip glue, TeX inserts \lineskip glue. In this particular case, nothing is done because all the parameters are zero. Only the flexible \vskip -3pt plus 3fil glue is present. We want 2pt at the top and 2pt at the bottom and to reach the 3pt goal, so -1pt glue results.
The box will be 3pt high as requested and 2pt deep.


Exercise 12.8
Here is a TikZ illustration of the three boxes:

\documentclass[tikz,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.8pt]
  \filldraw (0,0) circle[radius=1pt] node[left] {\tiny RP of box 3};
  \filldraw (0.75,-3) circle[radius=1pt];
  \filldraw (1,0) circle[radius=1pt];
  \draw[xshift=0.75cm,densely dashed] (0,-1) rectangle (1,1);
  \draw[xshift=0.75cm,yshift=-3cm] (0,-1) rectangle (1,1);
  \draw[xshift=1cm] (0,-2) rectangle (2,2);
  \draw[magenta] (0,-4.02) rectangle (3.02,2.02);
  \draw[<->] (0,0) --node[above] {\tiny 0.75 pt} (0.75,0);
  \draw[<->] (0.75,1.1) --node[above] {\tiny 0.25 pt} (1,1.1);
  \draw[<->] (0.65,-1) -- node[left] {\tiny 3 pt} (0.65,-4);
  \node at (1.25,-3) {\tiny box 1};
  \node at (2.2,0) {\tiny box 2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Thanks for the elegant diagram, I didn't notice they are overlapped.

Exercise 12.12
Since the last box (box2) is followed by glue (\vss), the depth of box4 is zero.

The natural glue between box1 and box2 is (9pt minus 3fil)-(1pt)-(2pt) = (6pt minus 3fil)

The natural height of box4 is the summation of:

0pt (from \vss)
2pt (from box1)
6pt (from glue between box1 and box2)
4pt (from box2)
0pt (from \vss)

that is 12pt in total.

The desired height is 4pt, which means that the shrinking amount of 8pt is needed.

The shrinkability comes from three parts:

1fil (from \vss)
3fil (from the glue between box1 and box2)
1fil (from another \vss)

that is 5fil in total. So the computed shrinking amount is 1.6pt, 4.8pt, 1.6pt.

The box4 is composed of five items:

\vskip -1.6pt
box1
\vskip 1.2pt
box2 (shifted to the left by 4pt)
\vskip -1.6pt



Reference point and visual illustration
I use the lua-visual-debug package to show how box4 looks like. To make the observation easier, I increased all the parameters by 10 times.
% compile with luatex
\input lua-visual-debug.sty
% Exercise 12.12
\baselineskip = 90pt minus 3fil
\lineskiplimit=0pt
\lineskip=0pt
\setbox1=\hbox{\vrule height10pt depth10pt width10pt}
\setbox2=\hbox{\vrule height20pt depth20pt width20pt}
\setbox4=\vbox to40pt{\vss\box1\moveleft40pt\box2\vss}
hello world\box4\relax hello

\bye


box4 is indicated by the red rectangle and as can be seen, it's 1pt wide, 4pt high.

Thanks for sooooo elegant to use lua-visual-debug.sty to show the width. However I still wonder why the effect of the above or below in \hbox will change the reference point, while the \moveleft and \moveright didn't widen the \box4? Where can I learn about that?

No. The \raise and \lower operation will not move the reference point vertically.

Test this: `\input lua-visual-debug.sty
\baselineskip=0pt
\lineskiplimit=0pt
\lineskip=0pt
\setbox1=\hbox{\vrule height10pt depth10pt width10pt}
\setbox2=\hbox{\lower5pt\box1}
hello\copy2 \the\ht2\ \the\dp2
\bye`

thanks to Stephen, I made a mistake just now, the \raise and \lower operation actually will not move the reference point, but they enlarge the sum of height and depth; however the case in 12.12, it dosen't widen the \box4, which I regeaded is a bit  inconsistency of the shift operattion here....

Maybe I mistake something.... How could we define the width of a box? As I know, the width is the horizontal length between the reference point(RP) and the widest length of every box inside the biggest one? And so sorry for my first comment, what I think there remains some inconsistency is rooted that, with \above and \lower, the vertical length of the \box3 be larger(in Question12.8), while with \moveleft and \moveright didn't enlarge the width of \box4(in Question12.12)?

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264289/why-does-moveleft-not-contribute-to-width-but-moveright-does for the definition of width.

Ops, I forget to search first on the tse, the link perfectly answered my doubt! the width in onlt that the RP to the rightest length of enclosed box extends, and both \moveleft and \above won't change the RP. Thanks for yr kindness!
